# Validation MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I already set validation in all my output that works fine but I have a lot of view and a next button, I want that button to be disabled every time there is an error in the output, it's already set on IsValid and I did this in the code behind of the view:

```
private void abc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Validation.GetHasError(CinInput) == true|| .......)
    Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++Nope+++++++++++++++++");
    else
    Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++OK+++++++++++++++++");
}
```

I need a solution to bind the the result to my viewmodel so i can set isvalid to false any suggestion?

Comment: This is C# not C code right? Please correct the tag to reach the right people.

Comment: How are you doing your validation? ValidationRules, or IDataErrorinfo?

Comment: I am currently using ValidationRules in MVVM pattern

Comment: shortly i need to send a bool or a response from my codebehind to my viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using data binding then its possible to pass a command or command parameter to the viewmodel. 
Looks like you're not following MVVM pattern from your `abc_click`.

You can access your viewmodel like this from your code behind :

```
var viewModel = DataContext as ViewModelClassName;
viewModel.SomeBooleanProperty = true; // Or false
```